# In the laravel, When I want to login then it goes else statement and show error

Tags: laravel

When I want to login it always shows the `else` statement. please help me I don't understand what's the problem because I am new in Laravel

---

#### web.php

```
route::get('show_login',[RegiController::class,'showlogin']);
route::post('login_data',[RegiController::class,'loginProcess']);
route::post('sing_vw',[RegiController::class,'singup']);
route::get('sing-vw',[RegiController::class,'sing_up']);
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

#### RegiController

```
public function loginProcess(Request $request)
{
     $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
  

     if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
  
         echo 'login successful';
     } else {
         echo 'error';
     }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating a new user? Are you using Laravel's built in way or your own code?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
 echo 'login successful';
}
```

Try that way instead of `attempt`

Edit based on comments:

Since you have also this method failing an assumption is that you store the password in the wrong format in the DB.

Password must be hashed so in order to create a password from your seeder or your registration form the password field should be inserted like:

```
'password' => bcrypt('Justmypassword'),
```

This will store the password of the user hashed in the db table and then you can login by using the email and the password `Justmypassword` to login.

Auth login of laravel gets your input password value, hashes it and matches it with the hashed password value of the email you claim to be yours to login.

That means that if you don't hash your password before insert it, then your password field will have a normal string but laravel will try to match the hashed string with the plain string which will cause to fail.

Comment: It also shows else statement. I gave the right email and passward and show else statement.

Comment: How did you set the users password? Did you manually update the password field in the database?

Comment: Yes I manually create a table for signup and I want to access the login function but it always shows else statements

Comment: Could you rewrite this login code for me?

Comment: It's not about login, it's about how you store users in your database. Please read my answer i explain in details.

Comment: Thank you, I got the solution